# How to add dollar amounts in org mode?

Tags: org-mode

Given something like:

```
| $1.10 |   |
| $2.20 |   |
| $3.30 |   |
|       |   |
```

How do you add the amounts with $-sign? `C-c +` does not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: in the form that you want to do it, it isn't possible.  Sigil (the dollar sign) is used in Org mode formulas for special purposes such as denoting a column or a name of a variable.  However, you could use the same units, but expressed differently.  For instance, you could use Calc to add currency units like this:

1. <kbd>C-x * c</kbd> - opens calculator.
2. <kbd>'</kbd>`usd`<kbd>RET</kbd> - puts the word `usd` on stack.
3. <kbd>u c</kbd> *answer prompts* - creates a new fundamental unit named `usd`.
4. <kbd>u p</kbd> saves units for future use.
5. <kbd>'</kbd>`1.13 usd`<kbd>RET</kbd> - puts `1.13 usd` on stack.
6. <kbd>u c</kbd> creates new units, when prompted for units name answer with `eur`.
7. <kbd>u p</kbd> save units again.

Alternatively, you could locate the Calc settings file (by examining <kbd>M-:</kbd>`calc-settings-file`, which is typically `~/.emacs.d/calc.el`) and add:

```
(setq math-additional-units '(
  (eur "1.13 * usd" "Euro")
  (usd nil "United States Dollar")))
```

to this file.  (You will only need to do this once.)

Now, you can write something like this in your Org file:

```
| 1.10 usd | 6.886 usd |
| 2.20 eur |           |
| 3.30 usd |           |
#+tblfm: @1$2=usimplify(vsum(@1$1..@3$1))
```