# Number-separators in org-mode tables

Tags: org-mode, org-table, formula

I often paste org-mode tables numbers that are e.g. space-separated. Then I have to delete spaces before things like `=$2/2` work correctly. Is there a way to change "number format", e.g. plug in a general function to parse input numbers in org-mode tables?

As an example, I'd like

```
| 100 000 | 0 |
#+TBLFM: $2=$1/2
```

to give 50000, not 0, in column two (I don't care that the output is not space-separated).

I know about `;N`, but that doesn't work either:

```
| 100 000 | 50 |
#+TBLFM: $2=$1/2;N
```

and I'd rather have something that works on the full table because I'm sure to forget to put it on each formula.

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to use " " as separator rather than the normal "|" ?

Comment: No, see my edit :)

Answer (score 4):

Just use [a little lisp](https://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Lisp.html#Formula-syntax-for-Lisp) to transform the cell string to a valid number.

You can use a lisp form as cell formula if you start the formula with apostrophe and parenthesis `'(`.

Org-table cell references within lisp forms are resolved as strings by default. If you can add another column to your table you can use a lisp form as simple and self-explanatory as `(cl-remove ?\s $1)`.
There `?\s` is the space character which is removed from the cell string `"100 000"` of cell `$1`. The resulting string is inserted in the target column `$2`.
You can process the result in further columns.

If you really want the result in the second column you must transform the compressed string into a number and process it in lisp.

The first table in the following example uses the easy lisp part the second table uses the variant with only two columns.

```org
| 100 000 | 100000 |  50000 |
| 250 842 | 250842 | 125421 |
#+TBLFM: $2='(cl-remove ?\s $1)::$3=$2/2

| 100 000 |  50000 |
| 250 842 | 125421 |
#+TBLFM: $2='(/ (string-to-number (cl-remove ?\s $1)) 2)
```

Comment: nice! I often want to use `,` for legibility, now I can. Doesn't work for leading dollar signs though - do you know how to parse numbers like `$100,000` in org tables?

Comment: @Tyler That's pityingly https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/15076/how-to-add-dollar-amounts-in-org-mode. It happens in the substitution phase before the evaluation phase.

Comment: hm, is there a way to apply a filter like that to more formulas, or shorten it a bit? I mean, it works, but it'll get quite verbose with several formulas …

Answer (score -1):

org table cells are not limited to a single number. So you cannot use spaces as decimal separator (who does that?)

If these come from excel, you can adjust the format to use no decimal separator.

Comment: Space is the character used as thousand separator in Swedish. 1 000 000 is a million with Swedish notation.